# how can i auto align a div to <a> tag on document

Tags: jquery

i have a div i.e

```
<div id="data_sprite">Jquery ajax data here</div>
```

and it is invisible....

now suppose i have my first `<a>` tag on top of document and 2nd `<a>` tag on bottom of document...
now what i want is that if i click on `<a>` on top of page the div auto align with its top right corner and when i click on `<a>` at bottom the div should auto align with its top right corner how can i achieve that with jquery or what ever....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JQuery, you can try something like that, assuming `ajaxlink` is a class used for both your  tags:

```
$('.ajaxlink').click(function() {
  var position = $(this).offset();
  position.left = position.left + $(this).width() - $('#data_sprite').width();
  position.top = position.top + $(this).height();
  $('#data_sprite').css(position)
});
```